# How to concatenate a constant similar to concatenation of strings?

Tags: php, constants

```
define('HOUSEHOLD_CHILD1','custom_16');
define('HOUSEHOLD_CHILD2','custom_14');
define('HOUSEHOLD_CHILD3','custom_13');
define('HOUSEHOLD_CHILD4','custom_12');


function household_function() {

$vari = array();
$var['household'][HOUSEHOLD_CHILD1] = $_SESSION['household_membership'][1];
$var['household'][HOUSEHOLD_CHILD2] = $_SESSION['household_membership'][2];
$var['household'][HOUSEHOLD_CHILD3] = $_SESSION['household_membership'][3];


}
```

I want to implement the above code in foreach loop
like something similar to concatenate.

it should be something similar to this

```
foreach($_SESSION['household'] as $key => $value) {
$var['household'][HOUSEHOLD_CHILDi] = [i];//i need to concatenate the constant
//to something similar we do for string
}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to eval a string to access a constant.

Comment: What is `[i]` supposed to do? If you're trying to add the literal string `[i]`, then you can use the following: `$var['household'][HOUSEHOLD_CHILD.$i] = '[i]';`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`constant`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function will serve your purpose:

```
define('HOUSEHOLD_CHILD1','custom_16');
define('HOUSEHOLD_CHILD2','custom_14');
define('HOUSEHOLD_CHILD3','custom_13');
define('HOUSEHOLD_CHILD4','custom_12');

for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
print(constant("HOUSEHOLD_CHILD".$i).PHP_EOL);
}
```

The output of the given code will be:

> `custom_16`
>   `custom_14`
>   `custom_13`
>   `custom_12`

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/132796)